# React wait for one loop (and setState) to finish before another loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, foreach, state

```
 handleSubmit = () => {
    this.setState({ modalState: false })

    this.state.codeToClass.forEach((code, classId, map) => {
      const cr = _.find(this.state.classRoles, { id: classId })

      if (code === cr.classCode) {
        console.log('here')
        this.setState(state => ({ 
          classRoles: state.classRoles.map((cc) => {
            console.log(cc.id)
            console.log(classId)
            console.log(cc.id === classId)
            if (cc.id === classId) {
              console.log('here1')
              return {
                ...cc,
                role: 'TA',
              }
            }
            console.log('what')
            return cc
          }),
        }), ()=> console.log(this.state.classRoles)) //this is called later
        
      } else {
        NotificationManager.error('Failed to register as TA.')
      }
    })
    console.log(this.state.classRoles) //this is called first
    this.state.classRoles.forEach((c) => {
      if (c.role === '') {
        api.deleteClassUser(c.id, this.state.user.id)
      } else {
        api.postAddClass(c.id, this.state.user.id, c.role)
        console.log(c)
      }
    })

    EventEmitter.publish('currentlyEnrolled', this.state.classRoles)
  }
```

I'm trying to run the second forEach after the first forEach has finished,i.e. state has been updated. But it keeps running in this order. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options.

1. Use Promise
2. Async await

Since map can be used with await, I think

```
const tempState = this.state.codeToclass;
await tempState.map(...
```

This way can work :)

Comment: Yes he should indeed need to use Promise but that method is not awaitable.

Answer (score 0):

`Promise` is your friend.

```
// You map your operations in to Promises.
 const promises = this.state.codeToClass.map((code, classId, map) => {
   return new Promise(resolve=>{
      const cr = _.find(this.state.classRoles, { id: classId })

      if (code === cr.classCode) {
        console.log('here')
        this.setState(state => ({ 
          classRoles: state.classRoles.map((cc) => {
            console.log(cc.id)
            console.log(classId)
            console.log(cc.id === classId)
            if (cc.id === classId) {
              console.log('here1')
              return {
                ...cc,
                role: 'TA',
              }
            }
            console.log('what')
            return cc
          }),
        }), ()=> resolve()) //this is called later
        
      } else {
        NotificationManager.error('Failed to register as TA.')
      }
    })
})

// and then you wait for all of the promises

await Promise.All(promises);
// then continue to execution
```

Answer (score 0):

this.setState is an asynchronous operation.

You can try something like this:

```
handleSubmit = () => {
   //some code...
   
   this.setState(state => ({
      state.codeToClass.forEach((...args) => {
         //logic to update the state...
      });
   }), setClassRoles); //call a function after the state value has updated
   
}

setClassRoles = () => {
    this.state.classRoles.forEach((...args) => {
        //your code...
    });
    EventEmitter.publish('currentlyEnrolled', this.state.classRoles)
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but foreach needs to be inside the setState function in order to meet OPs requirements.